# Swift: NSDate minus NSDate in hours

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have a model in Swift with an `NSDate` field named `expirationDate` and I want to calculate the **hours remaining** before expiration based on the current date.

Is there an easy way to do this with existing `NSDate` functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't check now, but should be something like

```
expirationDate.timeIntervalSinceNow / 3600
```

Comment: This is better than my answer, I completely spaced on timeIntervalSinceNow even being a thing. Your answer works in the REPL without modification.

Answer (score 2):

Just find the number of seconds (`NSTimeInterval`) between the two dates ('now' and your expiration date) and divide by 60*60 = 3600:

```
let secondsUntilExpiration = expirationDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate());

let hoursUntilExpiration = secondsUntilExpiration / 3600
```

For example:

```
  7> let now = NSDate() 
now: NSDate = 2016-02-01 03:44:06 UTC
  8> let expirationDate = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*10) // ten hours from now
expirationDate: NSDate = 2016-02-01 13:44:06 UTC
  9> let secondsUntilExpiration = expirationDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate()); 
secondsUntilExpiration: NSTimeInterval = 35991.422316968441
 10> let hoursUntilExpiration = secondsUntilExpiration / 3600 
hoursUntilExpiration: Double = 9.9976173102690122 
// Slightly less than the 10 hours above because of the time it took me to type.
```